# How to use CATX function in SAS

Tags: function, sas

I got "ItIsBlue" by following program. If it's word1 to word3 in order, I would get "IsItBlue", I think. Why?? Please give me some advice.

```
data dt00;
 word1 = 'Is';
 word2 = 'It';
 word3 = 'Blue';
 all = catx(word1, word2, word3);
run;
```

Comment: Please include unexpected behaviour or errors in your question or explain how it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to CATX() is the string you want to insert between the non-missing values of the other arguments.

Typically it is used to insert a delimiter in a list of values.

```
var1=1;
var2=2;
var3=.;
var4=4;
var5=5;
list=catx(',',of var1-var5);
```

Will result in LIST being set to the string

```
1,2,4,5
```

If you wanted the arguments concatenated in the order they are listed use the CATS() function instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it. CATS() is best answer for this case.